# Uploading files to Liferay server

Tags: java, api, file-upload, liferay, portal

I'm using Liferay 6.2 CE and I would like to add a simple functionality in which administrator can upload files to liferay server and add hyperlink to this file on the page.

I've found in Liferay's 6.1 documentation that in that version administrator could just create a data list and add File Upload field there as shown below:
[image]

Unfortunately in Liferay 6.2 this field doesn't exist (I'm confused here what's the reason):
[image]

I also saw that during new blog post creation, there is this HTML in-browser editor that has functionality to add images. When pressed, user can select a file from a hard drive which is then uploaded to liferay server and added as `<img>` tag to the blog editor and links to directory that looks like that: `/documents/11469/0/UPLOADED_FILE.zip/`.

[image]

But it's not intuitive for a user to upload normal files (e.g. .zip file), by using image uploader and manually editing the source code to change `<img>` tags to normal `<a>` anchors.

So my question is whether I need to solve described problem programatically using API (I believe that `DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil` is used for that purpose) or is there any other way to achieve this using liferay functionalities?

Comment: Why you don't use the field "Document"?

Comment: I've added `Document` field to my custom list and document is now uploaded. That's already big improvement. :) But now anonymous user sees only document name and is unable to download it. Could you tell me also how can I allow even not signed in users to download files?

Comment: Make a Screenshot, better create new Question.

Comment: @Mark I've created new question as you suggested: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089888/downloading-files-that-has-been-uploaded-via-dynamic-data-list-in-liferay-portal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "FileUpload" field by Liferay 6.1 is renamed to "Document" field in Liferay 6.2.

Comment: But the Document field uses the Documents and Media library. If you want to create a data list for guests, they'll not be able to attach a file due to incorrect permissions... Is there a way to add a simple file upload field?