# Downloading files that has been uploaded via dynamic data list in Liferay portal

Tags: java, api, download, liferay, portal

[I'm uploading files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087339/uploading-files-to-liferay-server/21089309?noredirect=1#21089309) via dynamic data list `Document` field. Now I would like to allow anonymous users to download those files, but currently they see only file name without the link to file:
[image]

Do you have any suggestions about how can I achieve that?

Edit:
As @Mark suggested, I've created Display Templated and in freemarker editor I've selected `Display and Media` field. It generated following code in my .ftl file:

```
<a href="${ddmUtil.getDisplayFieldValue(themeDisplay, cur_record.getFieldValue("Documents_and_Media1422", locale), cur_record.getFieldType("Documents_and_Media1422"))}">

${languageUtil.format(locale, "download-x", "Documents and Media")}

</a>
```

I've saved changes and refreshed page. It gave me following error:
`Expression cur_record is undefined on line 9, column 3 in 10157#10197#16569.`

Shouldn't cur_record be populated by the liferay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new "Display Template" witch include the link to the Document:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Define the `records` variable:

```
<#assign DDLRecordLocalService = serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.dynamicdatalists.service.DDLRecordLocalService")>
<#assign records = DDLRecordLocalService.getRecords(reserved_record_set_id)>

<#if records?has_content>
    <#list records as cur_record>

       <a href="${ddmUtil.getDisplayFieldValue(themeDisplay, cur_record.getFieldValue("Documents_and_Media1422", locale), cur_record.getFieldType("Documents_and_Media1422"))}">
           ${languageUtil.format(locale, "download-x", "Documents and Media")}
       </a>
    </#list>
</#if>
```

Also, due to bug https://support.liferay.com/browse/LPS-43149, update the `portal-ext.properties`:
[Liferay: How to configure Liferay Portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983343/liferay-how-to-configure-liferay-portal)

Comment: When I include link to `Display Templates` it throws an error. I've updated my question with more details.

Comment: It works :) I just have 2 follow-up questions: 1)What does the empty property `freemarker.engine.restricted.variables=` actually do? 2) Is there any helper for retrieving uploaded file name or do I need to parse the result of getDisplayFieldValue(...) by myself (it looks like `/documents/11469/0/test_doc_name.zip/878ee131-bde0-4055-9f5b-7e9342fd73e1`, and I want to get only `test_doc_name.zip`)?

Comment: 1) See portal.properties http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html

Comment: 2) it's need some more time for solution, create better new question, may be some one else can quickly answer this.

Comment: Got it. @Mark, once again thank you for your help :).